# Bernstein polynomial type for quadratic clipping

Tags: beginner, julia

I would like to implement a Bernstein polynomial class in Julia for learning purposes. The goal in the end is to implement the quadratic clipping algorithm from [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167839607000106). I am completely new to Julia coming from Python + Numpy + Numba, so I want to make sure that I program in the canonical Julia way when using Julia.

The naming of variables follows the aforementioned paper.

```
using Polynomials

type Bernstein
    n::Integer
    i::Integer
    α::Real
    β::Real
end
Bernstein(n, i) = Bernstein(n, i, 0., 1.)

Base.string(B::Bernstein) = "Bernstein $(get_p(B))"
Base.show(io::IO, B::Bernstein) = print(io, string(B))
Base.display(io::IO, B::Bernstein) = print(io, string(B))

function get_p(n, i, α=0, β=1)
    @assert β >= α "Invalid interval"
    return (binomial(n, i)
            * poly([α for _ in 1:i])
            * poly([β for _ in 1:(n - i)])
            * (-1)^(n - i)
            / (β - α)^n)
end
get_p(B::Bernstein) = get_p(B.n, B.i, B.α, B.β)

function ∫(p::Poly, α=NaN, β=NaN)
    integrated = polyint(p)
    if isequal(α, NaN) || isequal(β, NaN)
        return integrated
    else
        return integrated(β) - integrated(α)
    end
end

function inner_product(p::Poly, q::Poly, α=0., β=1.)
    @assert β >= α "Invalid interval"
    ∫(p * q, α, β)
end

function inner_product(B::Bernstein, Q::Bernstein)
    @assert B.α >= Q.α "Invalid interval"
    @assert B.β >= Q.β "Invalid interval"
    m, i, n, j, α, β = B.n, B.i, Q.n, Q.i, B.α, B.β
    (β - α)binomial(m, i)binomial(n, j) / ((m + n + 1)binomial(m + n, i + j))
end

# QUESTION: Is it possible to automatically account for commutativity?
(inner_product(p::Poly, B::Bernstein)
 = inner_product(B::Bernstein, p::Poly)
 = inner_product(B.p, p::Poly))

function Base.LinAlg.norm(q::Poly, α=0., β=1.)
    @assert β >= α "Invalid interval"
    √inner_product(q, q) / (β - α)
end

function Base.LinAlg.norm(B::Bernstein)
    √inner_product(B, B) / (B.β - B.α)
end

B = Bernstein(3, 2)
Q = Bernstein(4, 3)

inner_product(B, Q)
norm(B)
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code uses Julia 1.0.  Full code as a Pkg3 project is available [here](https://github.com/phipsgabler/Bernstein.jl).

### Preliminaries

There's enough code for it to get its own module.  This also makes testing easier.

```
module Bernstein

using Polynomials

import Base: convert, promote_rule, show
import LinearAlgebra: dot, norm
import Polynomials: poly
```

Since we're in a module, we must define the exported things.  Since most of the things is just
overloaded methods, only the type remains.

```
export BernsteinPoly
```

You do this check so often, we can factor it out.  Alternative: using a separate type
for intervals.

```
macro checkinterval(α, β)
    :(@assert $(esc(α)) <= $(esc(β)) "Invalid interval")
end
```

Parametrization by a constrained type is [better](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-fields-with-abstract-type-1) than fields of an abstract type.  But in the case of `n` and `i`, concrete `Int`s make more sense, since they represent natural numbers
always (this makes conversions below easier).
And I'm calling it `BernsteinPoly`, since it is a variant of `Poly`.

```
struct BernsteinPoly{T<:Number}
    n::Int
    i::Int
    α::T
    β::T
end

BernsteinPoly(n, i) = BernsteinPoly(n, i, 0.0, 1.0)
```

Just implementing `show` using `print` is the recommended way for [custom pretty-printing](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0/manual/types/#man-custom-pretty-printing-1). Here, we can reuse `Polynomials.printpoly` for nicer and more consistent formatting:

```
function show(io::IO, b::BernsteinPoly)
    print(io, "BernsteinPoly(")
    Polynomials.printpoly(io, poly(b))
    print(io, ")")
end
```

### Conversions

`get_p` was essentially the conversion from `BernsteinPoly` to `Poly`.  We can replace this
by the implementation of proper `convert` methods.  The default parameters are unnecessary,
since already occuring defaulted in the `BernsteinPoly` constructor.

```
function convert(::Type{Poly{S}}, b::BernsteinPoly) where {S<:Number}
    n, i, α, β = b.n, b.i, convert(S, b.α), convert(S, b.β)
    @checkinterval α β

    return (binomial(n, i)
            * poly(fill(α, i))     # `fill` instead of list comprehension
            * poly(fill(β, n - i))
            * (-1)^(n - i)
            / (β - α)^n)
end
```

This allows you to just say `convert(Poly, b)`, automatically reusing the inner type of `b`

```
convert(::Type{Poly}, b::BernsteinPoly{T}) where {T<:Number} =
    convert(Poly{T}, b)
```

While we're at it: conversion between different `BernsteinPoly` values

```
convert(::Type{BernsteinPoly{S}}, b::BernsteinPoly) where {S<:Number} =
    BernsteinPoly(b.n, b.i, convert(S, b.α), convert(S, b.β))
```

If we're handling different representations, we sometimes need to determine the "most general"
form, which is called promotion:

```
promote_rule(a::Type{BernsteinPoly{S}}, b::Type{Poly{T}}) where {S<:Number, T<:Number} =
    Poly{promote_type(S, T)}

promote_rule(::Type{BernsteinPoly{S}}, ::Type{BernsteinPoly{T}}) where {S<:Number, T<:Number} = 
    BernsteinPoly{promote_type(S, T)}
```

Also add a method to the `poly` smart constuctor, which is now trivial:

```
poly(b::BernsteinPoly) = convert(Poly, b)
```

### Linear Algebra

Now to the linear algebra part.  We could add methods to `dot` and `norm` from `LinearAlgebra`:

```
function dot(p::Poly{T}, q::Poly{T}, α = zero(T), β = one(T)) where {T<:Number}
    @checkinterval α β
    polyint(p * q, α, β)
end
```

And the norm induced by that inner product:

```
function norm(q::Poly{T}, α = zero(T), β = one(T)) where {T<:Number}
    @checkinterval α β
    √dot(q, q, α, β) / (β - α)
end
```

But such "overloads from outside" are frowned upon.  As of writing this, there's a [`norm`](https://github.com/JuliaMath/Polynomials.jl/blob/12d611fcd9b43300ecc83220b52c9127866b1a38/src/Polynomials.jl#L236) method
in `Polynomials`, but not `dot`.  There's an [issue](https://github.com/JuliaMath/Polynomials.jl/issues/110) about that; basically, `dot` is not
unique, hence we need to specify the intervals each time here.

For Bernstein polynomials, on the other hand, the inner product is defined uniquely, if I
understood correctly.

```
function dot(b::BernsteinPoly{T}, q::BernsteinPoly{T}) where {T<:Number}
    @checkinterval b.α q.α
    @checkinterval b.β q.β
    m, i, n, j, α, β = b.n, b.i, q.n, q.i, b.α, b.β
    (β - α) * binomial(m, i) * binomial(n, j) / ((m + n + 1) * binomial(m + n, i + j))
end
```

And the induced norm, as before.

```
function norm(b::BernsteinPoly)
    √dot(b, b) / (b.β - b.α)
end
```

As the last remaining question, how to do cross-type inner products.  If `dot` is defined for
`Poly` as written above, we can use `dot(promote(p, q)..., α, β)`.  But it's difficult to get
that working as a method.  I tried

```
dot(p::Union{Poly{T}, BernsteinPoly{T}}, q::Union{Poly{T}, BernsteinPoly{T}},
     α = zero(T), β = one(T)) where {T<:Number} =
     dot(promote(p, q)..., α, β)
```

but that doesn't work.  It's probably not recommended to do that anyway.  Use `promote`
explicitely where necessary.

### Example output

```
julia> B = BernsteinPoly(3, 2)
BernsteinPoly(3.0*x^2 - 3.0*x^3)

julia> Q = BernsteinPoly(4, 3)
BernsteinPoly(4.0*x^3 - 4.0*x^4)

julia> using LinearAlgebra

julia> dot(B, Q)
0.07142857142857142

julia> norm(B)
0.29277002188455997


end # module
```